# Normalizing probability over Expected Value

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm reading through this article regarding the Waiting Time Paradox

http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2018/09/13/waiting-time-paradox/

In the "Digging Deeper: Probabilities & Poisson Processes" section, the author writes:

> Let's denote by $p(T)$ the distribution of intervals $T$ between buses as they arrive at a bus stop.
>
> ...
>
> When a rider arrives at a bus stop at a random time, the probability
> of the time interval they experience will be affected by $p(T)$, but
> also by $T$ itself: the longer the interval, the larger the
> probability is that a passenger will experience it.
>
> So we can write the distribution of arrival times experienced by
> passengers: $$p_{exp}(T)∝Tp(T)$$
>
> The constant of proportionality comes from normalizing the
> distribution: $$p_{exp}(T)=\frac{T p(T)}{\int_{0}^{\infty}T p(T) dT}$$

I understand the denominator is just the Expected Value over all $T \geq 0$.I'm trying to get the intuition behind the fraction. Specifically:

1. How should I interpret the numerator and product $Tp(T)$? It seems to be just a weighted value of some time interval $T$ and just a fraction of the Expected Value.
2. Can you better explain how this definition of $p_{exp}(T)$ is the probability a person will have to wait within time interval $T$ until the next bus comes?

In regards to question #2, I tried doing a small example using finite sums. Suppose

$$T_1 = 5, \ T_2 = 15, \ p(T_1) = 1/4, \ p(T_2) = 3/4$$
So that Expected Value is $12.5$. Then:
$$p_{exp}(T_1) = 0.1$$
$$p_{exp}(T_2) = 0.9$$
So I'm not sure what I should understand about these probabilities. Does this mean the probability of a person having to wait in the 5 minute interval is 10%?

Comment: The authors of the linked article are guilty of an abuse when they write things like $\displaystyle \operatorname E(T) = \int_0^\infty T p(T)\, dT$ instead of something like $\displaystyle \operatorname E(T) = \int_0^\infty tp(t)\,dt.$ Without this distinction one cannot even understand something like $\Pr(T\le t),$ and there are logical arguments involving probability distributions that cannot otheriwise be properly understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than thinking of $Tp(T)$ as a weighted value of $T$, maybe it's more productive to think of it as a weighted value of $p(T)$. If all intervals were the same length, then when you arrive at the bus stop your probability of being in interval $T$ would simply be proportional to $T$. But since some intervals are longer than others, you are more likely to arrive during one of those intervals *simply because they are longer*, quite apart from how likely those intervals are to occur.

For example: if $T_1$ were 1 second long with probability $.99$ of occurring, and $T_2$ were ten hours long with probability $0.01$ of occurring, you would still be much more likely to arrive during $T_2$ than during $T_1$; even though $T_2$ is rare, whenever it *does* happen, it lasts for a very long time. So many arriving passengers arrive during $T_2$.

So: your probability of experiencing $T$ depends on (a) the probability of $T$ occurring, and (b) the length of $T$. That is why the numerator is a product of $p(T)$ and $T$.

So we know our probability of experiencing $T$ is proportional to (a) and to (b). But to calculate the actual probability, we need to normalize the product $Tp(T)$, by dividing it by the sum/integral of the probabilities of all possible intervals. When we do that, we have an expression $p_{exp}(T)=\frac{Tp(T)}{\int_0^\infty Tp(T)dT}$ which is a *normalized* product of the probability of $T$ and the length of $T$, which gives us the probability of experiencing $T$.